# "Reverse" order regex - closest "above" match

Tags: php, regex

this is example of some string.

```
<div>other text</div> some text abc , <div>need_match_this</div> bbbb <p>hsa</p> aa <span>hello</span>
```

I know only end of string `"<span>hello</span>"` and I need to match text in closest "above" div.

I used this regex:

```
\<div\>(.*?)\<\/div\>.*?\<span\>hello\<\/span\>
```

But this is not working for me because I need to return text of closest div only, not first div in string.

Is there any regex solution to resolve this?

Please help.

Thank you

Comment: The `<span>` element in your sample string is not enclosed in a `<div>` element, so the question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a negative lookahead based regex instead of in-between `.*?`, since `.*?` would also match opening or closing `div` tags.

```
<div>((?:(?!<\/?div>).)*?)<\/div>(?:(?!<\/?div>).)*?<span>hello<\/span>
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/mP4uN2/1)

`(?:(?!<\/?div>).)*?` forces the regex engine to match any character but not of `<div>` or `</div>`. That is, before matching each character, this regex would check for that particular character is not the starting character in `<div>` or `</div>` . If yes, then it would match that particular character. If no, match will fail abruptly and the following character won't be matched.

**Example:**

string - `<div></div>`

regex -  `<div>((?:(?!<\/?div>).)*?)<\/div>`

For this input, the above mentioned regex would capture the in-between empty string (*ie, the empty string exists between the opening and closing `div` tags*). `(?!<\/?div>).` in the above would check  for the following char must not be a starting char in `<div>` or `</div>` but this fails since the following char is `<` which is a staring char in `</div>`. Because we defined this particular regex to repeat zero or more times, `(?:(?!<\/?div>).)*?`, it captures the in-between empty string.